# How to optimize query update?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I run the following statement and it will  update beyond 93 million rows.

```
SET rowcount 10000
 update t 
  set [OC]=r.[OC]
  from [dbo].[Vente] t 
  inner join [dbo].[OC] r
   on t.[Date Time] between r.[DATE DEBUT] and r.[DATE FIN]
while @@rowcount>0
BEGIN
 update t 
  set [OC]=r.[OC]
   from [dbo].[Vente] t 
  inner join [dbo].[OC] r
  on t.[Date Time] between r.[DATE DEBUT] and r.[DATE FIN]
end
SET rowcount 0
```

How to optimize it ?

Comment: do you have and index on [Date time]?

Comment: Side note - setting rowcount like that is deprecated:

`Using SET ROWCOUNT will not affect DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in a future release of SQL Server. Avoid using SET ROWCOUNT with DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. For a similar behavior, use the TOP syntax.` (From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx))

Comment: Depending on your db's usage (are there other users / sessions?) you could turn off all triggers, drop all constraints and indexes and recreate them after the update.

Answer (score 0):

While having an index on t.[Date Time], I'd update in batches of data related to one day, something like:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime 
            = r.[DATE DEBUT] FROM [dbo].[OC] r,
        @EndDate datetime 
            = r.[DATE FIN] FROM [dbo].[OC] r

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN
    update t 
    set [OC]=r.[OC]
    from [dbo].[Vente] t 
    inner join [dbo].[OC] r
    on t.[Date Time] = @StartDate

    SELECT @NextDate = MIN(t.[Date Time])  
    from [dbo].[Vente] t 
    inner join [dbo].[OC] r on t.[Date Time] between r.[DATE DEBUT] and r.[DATE FIN]
    where t.[OC] <> r.[OC]

    SET @StartDate = @NextDate

END
```

You might need to do some conversions on the datetime fields to get the day. Depending on your data, you can also consider updating in batches of a fixed number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like yous update statement will go in an infinite loop because you don't exclude the updated records each time.

You need to add a condition to the update which is were t.[OC]<>r.[OC] to avoid unnecessary writes. And if t.OC is suppose to be null to be updated and not expected to change after the first update add where t.[OC] is null

Try to use Merge statement